# multi count in one query

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have three table like this:

manga

```
|   id  | sendby
------------------
|   1   |   1
|   2   |   1
|   3   |   1
|   4   |   1
```

chaprer

```
|   id  | sendby    | translator | graphic
-------------------------------------------
|   1   |   1       |   admin    |  other
|   2   |   1       |   admin    |  other
|   3   |   1       |   admin    |  admin
|   4   |   1       |   other    |  admin
```

user

```
|   userid  | username  
-----------------------
|      1    |   admin
```

I'm trying to count what ever i have sent, but the result is not correct.

i have tried below query:

```
SELECT username,
   SUM(
       CASE WHEN m.sendby = u.userid
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS manga,
   SUM(
       CASE WHEN c.sendby = u.userid
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS chapter,
   SUM(
       CASE WHEN c.translator = u.username
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS translator,
   SUM(
       CASE WHEN c.graphic = u.username
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   ) AS graphic
FROM user u
    left JOIN manga m 
        ON m.sendby = u.userid 
    left JOIN chapter c 
        ON c.sendby = u.userid 
where u.userid = '1'
```

but it's return this which is not correct:

manga : 16,
chapter : 16,
translator : 12,
graphic : 8

Comment: it's : manga:4, chapter:4, translator:3, graphic:2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query for this

```
select
  m.id,
  count(m.sendby) as Manga,
  lc.Chapter,
  rc.Translater,
  c.Grafix
from manga as m
  left join (select sendby, count(sendby) as Chapter from chaprer) as lc on lc.sendby  = m.sendby
  left join (select sendby, count(translater) as Translater from chaprer where translater = 'admin') as rc on rc.sendby  = m.sendby
  left join (select sendby, count(graphics) as Grafix from chaprer where translater = 'admin') as c on c.sendby  = m.sendby
```

EDITS
I have tested this query and this fetches this result

```
Query Result
id  Manga   Chapter Translater  Grafix
1   4       4       3           3
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use `left JOIN` intentionally? do you know how it [works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)? 
Using it twice made your select run on 16 rows result table.
Try first selecting all the results (*), and then fix your `FROM` clause to return the desired data to select from.

From your comment, it appears that you ment to use [Inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join).

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward approach would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT  username,
(SELECT COUNT(m.sendby) FROM manga m WHERE m.sendby= u.userid) AS manga,
(SELECT COUNT(c.sendby) FROM chapter c WHERE c.sendby= u.userid) AS chapter,
(SELECT COUNT(t.sendby) FROM chapter t WHERE t.translator= u.username) AS translator,
(SELECT COUNT(g.sendby) FROM chapter g WHERE g.graphic= u.username) AS graphic
FROM USER u
WHERE userid=1
```

You will see the problem in your original query if you run:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER u
    LEFT JOIN manga m 
        ON m.sendby = u.userid 
    LEFT JOIN chapter c 
        ON c.sendby = u.userid 
WHERE u.userid = '1'
```

The left join is returning duplicate rows.

Comment: this is dependant query and will take more execution time then left joins query

Comment: Sorry to say, but i would not recommend this approach. Running 4 different queries is not SQL best practice...

Comment: It really depends. The OP is querying based on 1 userid, and this approach is perfectly fine.